# Error while deploying components

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, deployment, quick-deploy

I am getting apex test failure messages while validating my Lightning components. I am using Ants tool.

Getting the same error  "**line -1, column -1: __MISSING LABEL__ PropertyFile - val dependent.class.invalid not found in section ContextExceptions 
Stack Trace: null**" for all classes

[image]

Has anyone encountered such a problem ? I can't for the life of me figure out what I am missing here..

Comment: This problem may be caused by a different failure in a dependent class. What happens if you fix the `WEBForecastSalesDivisionExtensionTest` method signature problem on the first line of the failure list?

Comment: This seems to be problem in your test class

Comment: I am getting the same error in all of my test classes.. Many of them are already available in the target org and very minor changes are added for them in this deployment. It should not cause any problem.

Comment: are you using some custom labels in your class?

Comment: Yes.. I use one custom label. But the class I  used it in is not in the  apex test failure classes list

Comment: Did you find some relevant answer to this. I am stuck in the same situation.

Comment: Yes..all these label error message were coming because of a problem in the class 'webforecastsalesdivsionextensiontest'. ( The first error message in the Apex test failures). You fix it the rest will be automatically fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what was causing the issue. As  *salesforce-hacker* pointed out, this problem was caused by a different failure in its dependent class `WEBForecastSalesDivisionExtension`. Once I fixed it, all the errors were auto fixed.

Comment: that's basically what I posted a couple of minutes before you...

Answer (score 1):

In the apex classes section of "setup" you can click "compile apex classes". This may show the invalid dependant class. This worked for me at least.

Comment: Thanks.. I had tried that before and the compilation was successful but still the issue remained.. Hwever I resolved it..